# Deploy-Publish error on Windows 10 IoT Core from laptop, (but from a desktop it works)

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, windows-iot, c#

I'm getting this issue when I try to publish on a Pi 2 or 3 a "universal app", (my project).

It's strange because from my desktop PC (Intel I7 - Win10 Pro - VS 2017), it works well but when I try to modify the project from my laptop (I3 - Win10 Home - VS 2017). I get this error code :

```
Gravity Code Description File Project Line Erase Status Error DEP 6720: The 'Core CLR' package could not be deployed. The package is not defined for OneCore.
```

Has do I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how on topic this question is, the fact that the issue appears when using your laptop but not your desktop suggests the problem lies with the laptop. In which case your question might be better asked on a site  like [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40701/error-dep6720-failed-to-deploy-package-core-clr-e0.html) . So I've proceed with a clean installation.